# Ubuntu resolution not detected correctly

Tags: ubuntu, resolution, xorg, xrandr

I recently installed Ubuntu on a dual boot with Windows, and I'm struggling to make Ubuntu detect correctly my resolution.

I have a 1920x1080 screen, but when I run `xrandr`, I get this

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1366 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
LVDS1 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 345mm x 194mm
1366x768       60.0*+
1360x768       59.8     60.0
1024x768       60.0
800x600        60.3     56.2
640x480        59.9
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

As I searched for a while on the internet, when I run `gtf 1920 1080 60`, I get that

```
# 1920x1080 @ 60.00 Hz (GTF) hsync: 67.08 kHz; pclk: 172.80 MHz
Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  172.80  1920 2040 2248 2576  1080 1081 1084 1118  -HSync +Vsyn
```

I try to add a new mode like this

```
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  172.80  1920 2040 2248 2576  1080 1081 1084 1118  -HSync +Vsync
```

And when I try `xrandr --addmode LVDS1 1920x1080_60.00`, I get this

```
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  37
  Current serial number in output stream:  38
```

After the `newmode`, `xrandr` gives me

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1366 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
LVDS1 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 345mm x 194mm
    1366x768       60.0*+
    1360x768       59.8     60.0
    1024x768       60.0
    800x600        60.3     56.2
    640x480        59.9
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    1920x1080_60.00 (0xbb)  172.8MHz
         h: width  1920 start 2040 end 2248 total 2576 skew    0 clock   67.1KHz
         v: height 1080 start 1081 end 1084 total 1118           clock   60.0Hz
```

Do you have any idea of what I could do to make it work ?

Thank you in advance.